# Checking if two strings match

Tags: c, string

I am trying to check whether an user input matches a variable in my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* subject1 = "math";
char input[10];

int main() 
{
    printf("Subject: ");
    scanf("%s", input);

    if(strcmp(input,subject1) == 0)
    {
        printf("cpi\n");
    }
    else if(strcmp(input,subject1) == 0)
    {
        printf("math\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I input the string "math",I get `cpi` in the output, instead of `math`. Why?

Comment: For which input? I.e. what is surprising you about that?

Comment: both test are same in if and else if, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Since your `input` array has space for *strings* up to 9 characters long, use `scanf("%9s", input);` to prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: edited, sorry. I am trying to check if they equal "math".

Comment: "If I input the string "math",I get cpi in the output," --> because `(strcmp("math","math") == 0)` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(strcmp(input,subject1) == 0)
```

Is true when you input math as strcmp() returns 0 if the arguments match. So what you want is

```
if(strcmp(input,subject1) != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the if-conditions are true here. So, when the first 'if' condition is satisfied and executed, it doesn't check the 'else if' condition. The 'else if' condition only gets checked and executed whenever all the previous 'if' conditions were false.

Hope this helped.